# find the critical value of r.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

For  the following equations sketch the bifurcation diagram, determine type of bifurcation, and find the critical value of $r$.

$$\dot{x} = rx + \cosh x$$

I seem to understand how to do the first two parts of the questions ( sketch the bifurcation diagram and determine type of bifurcation). Though I never really understood how to find THE VALUE of  "$r$" ....

Comment: Any comments on my reply to your earlier question on bifurcation?

Answer (score 2):

A critical value is a value where a bifurcation occurs.  Hint:  Look at the graph of the equation $r x + \cosh(x) = 0$, and see where the number of critical points changes.